# Variables not being able to be added

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

So I am trying to make a python discord bot, with a feature of PVP in it (based off of Jojo's Bizarre Adventures). I keep having this logic error where the bonus/ otherbonus doesn't get added to the chance. Sorry if this doesn't make sense but I've been trying to figure it out for a while.
**Here's the code where I believe this error is coming from:**

```
    elif otherstando == "Ultimate Life Form Vampiric Hamonic Spin Ratt Platinum Requiem Over Heaven Under Hell Alternate Universe Act 4 Love Train Bites The Dust":
        otherbonus = 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    
    otherbonus = otherbonus + other
    bonus = bonus + me

    print(bonus)
    
    embed = discord.Embed(title='***Your Bizarre Adventure***', description="A mini JJBA feature [<@"+ str(ctx.message.author.id) + "> / <@" + str(member.id) + ">]", color=0xFF000)

    embed.add_field(name="Online PVP", value="<@" + str(ctx.message.author.id) + "> [" + stando + "] __**VS**__ <@" + str(member.id) + "> [" + otherstando + "]", inline=False)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    otheron = "True"
    meon = "True"

    print("me " + str(ctx.message.author.id) + " " + str(me))
    print("other " + str(member.id) + " " + str(other))
```

The **print(bonus)** prints out 180, which isn't anywhere in the code. I can send the whole code if it helps, just tell me in replies. The command works perfectly but the bonus just doesn't get added. Anyways, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post a _MINIMAL_ reproducible example. We will NOT read your 100s of lines of irrelevant code.

Comment: recommendation for you. Instead of having this code, `if stando == "The Emperor" or stando == "Anubis" or stando == "Ratt" or stando == "Osiris" or stando == "White Album" or stando == "Mr. President" or stando == "The Sun":`       you can also write the code as `if stando in ("The Emperor", "Anubis", "Ratt", "Osiris", "White Album", "Mr. President", "The Sun"):`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to be `bonus` is 180 since you defined as `bonus = bonus + me`. For example, if `me` is 100 and `stando` is `Killer Queen [Alternative Universe]`. You can get the number.

Comment: How would I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have a few things going on. The first thing is you have a random function that generates a number. These two lines of code.

```
other = random.randint(1, 1000)
me = random.randint(1, 1000)
```

They can generate a value between 1 and 1000 for `other` and `me`.

Let's assume the value for `me` is `160`.

Let's also assume the value for `stando` is `Anubis`, then the if statement is true and `bonus` is assigned `20`

So the values for `bonus` is `20` and `me` is `160`
The code further down has

```
bonus = bonus + me # resulting in 20 + 160 = 180
```

So your code can get a value of 180.

Also, I wanted to give you some additional inputs to improve your code.

You could put all the values in the if statement into a list like this.

```
check_list = ["The Emperor","Anubis", "Ratt", "Osiris", "White Album", "Mr. President", "The Sun"]
```

Then you can check for

```
if stando in check_list:
```

This will be the same as

```
if stando == "The Emperor" or otherstando == "Anubis" or otherstando == "Ratt" or otherstando == "Osiris" or otherstando == "White Album" or otherstando == "Mr. President" or otherstando == "The Sun":
    bonus = 20
```

I also wanted to provide you some more options to consider.

Try this example and see if you can use something similar.

```
x = 10
y = 20
z = [10,11,12,13,14,15]

if (x or y) in z:
    print('either x or y has a value from z')
else:
    print('neither x nor y has a value from z')
```

If both `stando` and `otherstando` are checked for the same thing AND if you are going to assign the same value to `bonus` and `otherbonus`, you can do something similar to the above example.

Maybe you can try something like this.

```
check_list = ["The Emperor","Anubis", "Ratt", "Osiris", "White Album", "Mr. President", "The Sun"]
if (stando or otherstando) in check_list:
    bonus = otherbonus = 20
```